# Assign and use variable during for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the a dataset, containing about 4000 matrices in vector form, each of them should be named by the date it was created.

Right now I have the following:

```
dates <- unique(rcov_matrix$dateid)

for(k in dates){
  k <- matrix(0, 30, 30)
  for(i in 1:30){
    for (j in 1:i){
      number <- number + 1
      value <- rcov_matrix[1, number]
      k[i,j] <- value
      k[j,i] <- value
    }
  }
}
```

The code correctly assigns the entries of the vector to the matrix, but I only end up with one matrix named k in the end. 
I understand that this is because of the way variable names are assigned in R, but I could not find a viable solution for my problem in similar posts.

```
assign(k, matrix(0, 30, 30))
```

does not work because I have to reuse the variable name later in the next for loop.

How can I solve this? Or is there a more effective way to assign my values to the matrices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the simplest is to use `assign` at the end of the loop, rather than the start.

```
for (k in dates){
  This_k <- matrix(0, 30, 30)
  for(i in 1:30){
    for (j in 1:i){
      value <- rnorm(1)  # I use rnorm here to make the example reproducible
      This_k[i,j] <- value
      This_k[j,i] <- value
    }
  }
  assign(k, This_k)
}
```

Alternatively (and perhaps a little more efficient), you could put your matrices in a list and use list indexing:

```
klist = lapply(rep(0, length(dates)), matrix, 30, 30)
names(klist) = dates

for (k in dates){
  for(i in 1:30){
    for (j in 1:i){
      value <- rnorm(1)
      klist[[k]][i,j] <- value
      klist[[k]][j,i] <- value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the easiest solutions are the best! Thank you.

Comment: Yes the simple version can be best.  But in this case I prefer the 2nd list version both for greater efficiency (less copying of matrices, especially if they are large), and for ease of indexing later in your script. Basically when you have, as here, a "list" of similar objects with sequential names, the natural data structure to use is an actual `list`